# How come I cannot get my json file wordpress javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

It is code from treehouse to create autocomplete. Great code, the only problem is that I cannot get my own json file after i replace it. I use wordpress, my file name is autocomplete.json, you could see the code on the bottom of my code. it gave me the error autocomplete.json 404 Not Found. Does wordpress have some path to get the file, thanks.

```js
var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');
var input = document.getElementById('ajax');
// Create a new XMLHttpRequest.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Handle state changes for the request.
request.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
      // Parse the JSON
      var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      // Loop over the JSON array.
      jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
        // Create a new <option> element.
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        // Set the value using the item in the JSON array.
        option.value = item;
        // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>.
        dataList.appendChild(option);
      });

    } else {
      // An error occured :(
      input.placeholder = "Couldn't load datalist options :(";
    }
  }
};

// Update the placeholder text.
input.placeholder = "Loading options...";

// Set up and make the request.
request.open('GET', 'autocomplete.json', true);
request.send();
```

Comment: Try `/autocomplete.json` and put the file in your root folder !

Comment: try that already, not working

Comment: Put the full URL just to make sure !

Comment: what is the full URL?

Comment: e.g `http://example.com/autocomplete.json`

Comment: Thank you. Full url work. But do you any code to get the full url, because it will have different url if I change the theme. Thanks.